# Beautiful Soup Tutorial Error: jeriwieringa.com

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I run this code from the tutorial here (http://jeriwieringa.com/blog/2012/11/04/beautiful-soup-tutorial-part-1/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("43rd-congress.htm"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
names = link.contents[0]
fullLink = link.get('href')
print names
print fullLink
```

And I get this error:

```
File "soupexample.py", line 11, in <module>
fullLink = link.get('href')
link is not defined
```

Why would I need to define link in links for this loop? What's the logic? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you indent your for loop? I guess you forgot to indent the second line of the loop...

Comment: That doesn't look like a normal traceback. Are you running this in some IDE that intercepts errors and tries to show them to you more nicely?

Comment: @sashkello: that would give an IndentationError, which doesn't seem to be the OP's problem. (But obviously he needs to fix the indentation of the question to match his actual code if he wants us to debug his actual code, so it's still a good point to raise.)

Comment: @abarnert If the first line is indented and second is not, this would be the error...

Comment: Wow....I feel dumb.  I thought that did not matter. The indention matter.

Comment: You may want to go through a basic Python tutorial before trying to learn BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @RobB. Go through some basic Python tutorial, mate. But it is certainly weird that all the examples on that page miss indentation...

Comment: @Sashkello
 Thanks for the tip. I have done quite a few basic tutorials with codeacademy and LPTHW. I feel like I'm abusing stackoverflow.com with these simple questions which I should know the answers to. 

I feel like my checklist for errors should be...
    1. Indentions
    2. Check brackets and parentheses
    3. Check spelling

Any other ideas?

Comment: @RobB. Read up on debugging. This is something you need to master as a programmer. Start with simple things like printing your variables at some crucial points and identifying the exact place where things go wrong. The general idea is to also learn to "run" program in your mind. Go line-by-line and think as a computer :) Here it is simple you have `for link in links:` and so `link` is defined only within this loop. Obviously when you are out of the loop (end of indented part), there is no `link` any more and thus the error...

Comment: As soon as you know the line where the problem has happened, finding spelling errors or unmatched brackets should be easy (just staring at it long enough ;) ). Wrongly formed loop or if statements sometimes throw error on next line. I.e, if you forgot the `:`, it will be wrong indent error on the next line, so watch out for such things as well...

Comment: A visualizer like [this](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) is a great way to see what's going on for simple programs. And once you get the hang of it, you'll want to do things like "just run until this line and only show me the variable I care about instead of running every step and showing me everything", at which point you're ready for a real debugger. (The visualizer is still useful for many things even after you get there.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess mistake comes from here (somehow there is no indent in the example and there certainly should be):

```
for link in links:
    names = link.contents[0]
    fullLink = link.get('href')
    print names
    print fullLink
```